# What is a reliable way to include libraries for virtualenv python packages in nix?

Tags: python, gcc, nix, nixpkgs

I'll start by saying virtualenv is basically a requirement here since Nix is not yet being used by the rest of the development team. This [excellent guide on Python in Nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/python.md#how-to-consume-python-modules-using-pip-in-a-virtualenv-like-i-am-used-to-on-other-operating-systems-) doesn't quite drill down to this particular issue.

In some cases I can update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it gets to be rather tedious and potentially error prone due to the dynamic nature of Python (a particular branch could trigger the use of a library not previously included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`):

```
  shellHook = ''
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${mysql57}/lib:${gcc6}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  '';
```

Worse, the `${ggc6}/lib` doesn't work for me here, since the library I need (libatomic.so) is under the `*-gcc-6.4.0-lib/lib` directory, not the `*-gcc-6.4.0/lib` directory, and I'm not sure how to reference the former.

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/nix/store/x3x3si0pc3w0vam9jj308b0qhcv7zlg2-mysql-5.7.19/lib:/nix/store/mc8p626zjk9zlgji1i8f85nax4c62nrj-gcc-wrapper-6.4.0/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
```

Some output from find for libatomic:

```
/nix/store/rww78vdn2rkayrnqsjl8ib5iq2vfm3sw-gcc-6.4.0/lib/libatomic.a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
/nix/store/klqzvvcy1xyjjflmf7agryayc4s72jg2-gcc-6.4.0-lib/lib/libatomic.so.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
/nix/store/klqzvvcy1xyjjflmf7agryayc4s72jg2-gcc-6.4.0-lib/lib/libatomic.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
/nix/store/klqzvvcy1xyjjflmf7agryayc4s72jg2-gcc-6.4.0-lib/lib/libatomic.la                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
/nix/store/klqzvvcy1xyjjflmf7agryayc4s72jg2-gcc-6.4.0-lib/lib/libatomic.so.1.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the nixpkgs Python infrastructure much, so I'm not sure if there is a way to eliminate setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Recommendations for setting it:

- You can use `lib.makeLibraryPath` to make the process much less tedious. If you know that all the libraries that might be necessary are (mostly) in `buildDepends` anyway, you can use `lib.makeLibraryPath (buildDepends ++ [ anything else ])`.
- The issue with GCC libraries has to do with the fact that Nix needs wrapped versions of GCC, so `pkgs.gcc6` isn't the "raw" GCC derivation. You can use  `gcc6.cc.lib`, or, if you are using `makeLibraryPath`, just `gcc6.cc` will be enough (as `makeLibraryPath` will automatically figure out that the `lib` output is the correct one to look under).